# Java alternative for Ruby's vcr?

Tags: java, ruby, mocking, tdd, vcr

Is there a java alternative for [Ruby's VCR](https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr)?

As far as I understand, the benefits of using VCR are immense, you can run an "integration test" and record the results, store them some where locally. Now from the next time when you need to run your tests, you can mockup your actual database hits with the data recorded from the first run.

1. Is there something similar in java world?
2. If not, what kind of bottlenecks I might face if I try to implement it?

VCR only records HTTP interactions, but can such an approach be done to record, say any kind of database operations/function calls to other team's APIs which I don't need to test, basically this will relieve me from mocking up so many things by automating it.

[Here](https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-test-unit) is an example of VCR with Ruby's unit tests:

Comment: If you want repeatable tests that write to a database, check out [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [betamax](https://github.com/betamaxteam/betamax). It's a groovy port of VCR. It should work on the JVM with any language, I believe.

As for using a VCR-like library to record/playback DB interactions: Sven Fuchs tried this approach and [didn't see much benefit to it](http://svenfuchs.com/2011/02/09/recording-and-replaying-the-database-connection.html).

Comment: Thanks the reply, in case of Sven Fuchs, the database init time might be very low since he was using a regular rails project. But in my case, if I try to get around the database (in java) I will get a gain of 10mins of init time! I think I will try to write a java port sometime and see how it works for me. HTTP interaction recording is not my concern unfortunately.

Comment: betamax link is dead, updated link to github --> https://github.com/betamaxteam/betamax

Comment: betamax is no longer maintained. I wouldn't recommend relying on a library that is unmaintained

Answer (score 1):

Check out [anystub](https://github.com/anystub/anystub). this is java-lib. it allows to record/playback any `String get(String... keys)` invocations instead of only HTTP trafic.

Answer (score 1):

betamax has been abandoned. You may want to check out [mocktail](https://github.com/vashishthask/mocktail) which is a java-method level record and play mechanism. That means - record and play is applicable on almost anything, not just on HTTP.

Disclaimer: I created Mocktail

Comment: Nice library and good to recommend alternatives to the abandoned betamax, but please disclose that you are the maintainer of mocktail, it is customary on this site to put something like "Disclaimer: I have created mocktail" in answers like this.

Comment: Wasn't aware of it. Done that.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of this record-playback-concept is easyVCR, it is an MIT-licensed project backed by a company.

engineering-blog: https://www.easypost.com/blog/2022-10-04-vcr-the-must-have-companion-for-api-testing

github: https://github.com/EasyPost/easyvcr-java

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball I have no connection to the company, the project, or any of the people involved.

Comment: I just looked for more alternatives on the web because no suggestion here seem as mature and reliable as the python or ruby solution. Neither does this one, but it seems closer.